# else and conditional categorical statement in R

Tags: r

if (p$2=′0′|p$2=′a0′ and p$3=′0′|p$3='a0') {p$LTD=0 } else {p$LTD=1 } trying to implement if else statement in R return 0 or 1 depending of 2 and 3 else it is one

Comment: Hi Julia, I saw that you were trying to comment to @ThomasIsCoding's reply. Maybe you edit this post here? Or comment below his answer?

Comment: the result is 1 everywhere but was suppose to be either 1 or 0 depending of my p$2 and p$3 values

Comment: Error: unexpected '=' in "ifelse((PB$02t=='0'|PB$02=='D0') && (PB$03=='0'|PB$03=='D0'),PB$impact="

Comment: your column names are 02 and 03 ?

Comment: yes they are x03 and x03 to be more precise

Comment: if your data frame is PB, do PB$LTD = +((PB$x02t=='0'|PB$x02=='D0') & (PB$x03=='0'|PB$x03=='D0'))

Comment: PB$LTD should be 1 or 0...now it is 1 for all of them

Comment: Then all of them fulfill the condition? Hey you have to do dput(PB) and paste the output as part of your question.. Otherwise it's hard to know how it should work

Comment: nope that not the case that is the thing , tthey are not all fullfilling the condition s/d ber 40% / 60%

Comment: could you use `dput(p)` to share your data? otherwise it is difficult for others to help you

Comment: not possible to share the data

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
p$LTD <- ifelse(p$X2 %in% c("0","a0") & p$X3 %in% c("0","a0"),0 ,1)
```

I have no idea what is your desired output

**example with dummy data**

```
p <- data.frame("2" = c("a0","1","0","a0","a1"),
                "3" = c("0","a1","a0","0","0"))
> p
  X2 X3
1 a0  0
2  1 a1
3  0 a0
4 a0  0
5 a1  0
```

then

```
p$LTD <- ifelse(p$X2 %in% c("0","a0") & p$X3 %in% c("0","a0"),0 ,1)
> p
  X2 X3 LTD
1 a0  0   0
2  1 a1   1
3  0 a0   0
4 a0  0   0
5 a1  0   1
```

[image]

Comment: my desred outpout was to create a new column with result 0 or 1 as a categorical value

Comment: desired output (characters)

Comment: so now I have 12 columns from x1 to x12

Comment: and the conditions are if there is two a2 in a row for (x1 to x12)  answer p$ltd=1 or any a3 or a4 for any (x to x12) p$ltd=1  else p$ltd=0. how can I implemente it

Comment: I have no clues how to do it .?!

Comment: @julia try `p$LTD <- apply(p,1,function(v) ifelse(sum(v=="a2"`)==2|unlist(v) %in% c("a3","a4")),1,0))`

Comment: y$LTD<-apply(y,1,function(v) ifelse(sum(v=="d2")==2|unlist(v) %in% c("d3","d4"),1,0))                           error in the result why?  x1

x1   x2   x3      x4     x5    x6    x7    x8     x9   x10  x11  x12  LTD
d1 0 0 0 d0 d0 d0 d0 d0 d1 0 0 0                                                       d1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 d2 d2 0 0   s/d be 1

Comment: if I have d2 for march and d2 for June and 0 in between it is considered as 2 d2 in a row....not exactly what I was looking for